# How to install rattle in centos

Tags: r, rattle

While running rattle in my system I am getting this error

```
rattle()
```

Error: attempt to apply non-function
In addition: Warning message:
In method(obj, ...) : Unknown internal child: selection

I am using R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)

Comment: Hey could you add some more details. Also it seems incomplete as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer.
I have to install some of the packages in terminal . I installed it and it works.

```
sudo yum install gtk+-devel gtk2-devel
```